# Dropbox sync alike app, that use own web server

Tags: data-synchronization, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox-like client for FTP? or WebDAV? or CMIS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49628/dropbox-like-client-for-ftp-or-webdav-or-cmis)

Is there any Dropbox sync alike app , that can

-use own ftp server

-sync like Dropbox(if there is a change is local drive then auto upload to the ftp server)

Comment: Do you need GUI? Which OS?

Comment: If you have some to add to this to make it different than the other question, edit your question and flag for a second look.

Comment: macintosh operating system