# App or method to automatically sync photos to webdav server (FileRun)

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, data-synchronization, webdav

I'm looking for a way to automatically sync my photos to a self hosted webdav instance (in particular a FileRun instance, which is dav compatible).
I'd ideally not have to do anything, other than take photos, and then find the photos synced on the server. 
I already use FE File Explorer to do this manually (navigate to photos, select new ones, copy them manually to webdav server), but would like something that does this automatically.

Is there something like this out there? I mean other than syncing to iCloud... I would like this feature out of privacy considerations. I simply don't trust cloud services, other than self-hosted ones. For this reason, apps that require an account and store my data on their servers or even pass my data through their servers are not what I'm looking for.

Edit: I've searched before posting, [this question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375625/app-or-method-to-automatically-sync-photos-to-webdav-server-filerun) asks about outright replacing iCloud. I only need photos synced. I know it can be done manually I'm looking for something that does it automatically.

Edit 2: I'd love to find a free solution to do it if possible.

Comment: [Dropbox-like client for Macs to access existing FTP/WebDAV/CMIS storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49628/dropbox-like-client-for-macs-to-access-existing-ftp-webdav-cmis-storage)

Comment: thanks @ankii , not sure what to make of that link. I've got the part where I take the files off the cloud covered (i'm using linux btw, and have the webdav server mounted as a local drive). I need the part where stuff is synced between iphone and cloud.

Comment: Did you link to your own post?

Comment: Hah, it looks like i did just that. Unfortunately after so much time I don't remember the question I was actually trying to link to.